# PostgreSQL: Inserting High Quantity in Multi Tables with Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, postgresql, foreign-keys, npgsql

So, I'm working on a project that involves inserting a huge amount of data over the course of a day into three main tables. The three tables are all linked to each other.

Here are the tables:

```
event
    user_id
    event_time
    event_id (PRIMARY) (Serial Int)

subevent
    subevent_type
    subevent_value
    subevent_id (PRIMARY) (Serial Int)

event_relationship
    event_id (1)
    subevent_id (MANY)
```

`events` can happen at any moment, and when they do, I need to record the details of the `subevents` and insert them into the database. There can be anywhere from 5 to 500 `subevents` in one `event`. The reason I have a relationship table and not just a foreign key column in `subevents` is because there are other processes that add values to `subevents` that don't have parent `events`. Confusing, maybe.

By the end of one day, I maybe have inserted as many as 10 million `subevents` and 250,000 `events`. So speed is one of the most important things to me. One of the best ways I've found to insert them all together is using a `DO $$ DECLARE ... END$$;` command. I can declare temp integer values and capture the ids for the `events` and `subevents` that I insert and then insert them together into the `event_relationship` table.

Here is the code I'm currently running, which executes as PL/pgSql

```
DO $$ DECLARE _new_event_id INTEGER; _new_subevent_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO event (user_id, event_time) VALUES (@user_id, @event_time)
    RETURNING event_id INTO _new_event_id;

    INSERT INTO subevent (subevent_type, subevent_value)
    VALUES (@subevent_type, @subevent_value)
    RETURNING subevent_id INTO _new_subevent_id;

    INSERT INTO event_relationship VALUES (_new_event_id, _new_subevent_id);

END$$;
```

(The first insert is only once, the last two inserts are repeated for each subevent. I execute the command using C# and NpgSql and can build the command dynamically as the process runs.)

However, over the course of the day, this bogs down and my data starts to back up to the point where I can't insert it all fast enough. I'm just wondering if I'm taking the wrong approach here OR if there's another way to do what I'm already doing but in a faster manner.

Comment: if the subevebt -> event relationship really is N->1, you don't need a junction table. BTW: Please add the _real_ DDS to your question, including foreign keys and secondary indices.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you on?

Comment: PostgreSQL version 9.2

Comment: BTW: you seem to be suffering from the row-at-a-time syndrome. 250K records / day is 3 records / second. 10M records / day is 115 rec /sec. With one {round_trip+parse+execute+commit} per record that is going to be tight (8ms could even be the commit delay, on a slow disk in synchroneous mode). ERGO: batch your inserts, and at least use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a foreign key relationship and insert `null` in the referencing table:

```
create table t (i int primary key);
create table t2 (i int references t (i));

insert into t2 (i) values (null);
INSERT 0 1

insert into t2 (i) values (1);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "t2" violates foreign key constraint "t2_i_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (i)=(1) is not present in table "t".
```

Or have a special value like zero or -1 in the referenced table to be used for "orphan" subevents.

To lessen the load you can insert the subevents in a single command:

```
insert into subevent (subevent_type, subevent_value) values
(@subevent1_type, @subevent1_value),
(@subevent2_type, @subevent2_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using NpgSql, I assume you're a .net developer.

If the bottleneck is in the area of creating the sql commands, here is an article with some hints on improving insert performance: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2006/03/01/5-surefire-adonet-performance-tips.aspx . Among the techniques mentioned is the DbCommand.Prepare() method which I believe is similar to the "prepared statements" that wildplasser mentions.

If the bottleneck is during the actual insert, consider using multiple connections to the database server and doing the work in multiple threads.

Comment: Mutliple connections will only make things worse, competing with eachother: {making extra row-versions, doing lots of commits} The clue is: make the number of inserts per commit larger. (and maybe ven: the number of inserts per statement) FYI: I just ran a test, **in one transaction** it takes **less than 4 minutes** to insert 250K master + 10M detail records, including foreign key constraint validation.

Comment: It turns out more threads is not necessarily a bad thing, at least according to the testing that I have done. Each individual transaction might take longer, but at least the entirety of the process is finishing faster: In a batch of 800 events and 10,000 subevents, it took a single-threaded insert method 120 seconds to complete. On two threads, it only took 75 seconds. Across four threads, it took 45 seconds to complete. The total processing time was indeed greater, but given a server that can handle the multi-threading, it took less time to complete in practice.